# Emails stopped sending after the project was deployed on a real hosting

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I deployed the project on the real host, and email stopped sending. It works on the local host.
Here is the nodemailer settings:

```
var smtpTransport = nodeMailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  host: "smtp.gmail.com",
  auth: {
    user: "here is my gmail",
    pass: "here is password"
  }
});
```

Here is the data that was sent to me from the hosting:

List of POP3 IMAP and SMTP mail servers

Webmail: https://mail.ye4wrc7dna.nlnode.webrahost.eu

POP3/IMAP Server:
mail.webrahost.com
Port: 993
TLS/SSL

Outgoing Server (SMTP):
mail.webrahost.com
Port: 465
Connection security: SSL/TSL
(this server requires an encrypted connection)

The request comes to the server (checked through console.log), but the email is not sent. How to set up correctly? 
Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved in the following way. Technical support created an account at http://mail.webrahost.com/ for me, and then I entered this data into the settings of nodemailer.

```
var smtpTransport = nodeMailer.createTransport({
  host: "mail.webrahost.eu",
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: "my webrahost email",
    pass: "my password"
  }
});
```

Now email is working